# In dialogflow messenger the spacebar is not working

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have integrated the dialogflow messenger in my website, I have inserted the code in my header, now it is appearing on my website but when I tried to enter text, the spacebar does not work, I tried it on dialogflow try it now section, it works fine there.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing. You just cannot type a space into the message. Anyone from Google care to respond?

Here's the [Link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger) to the installation instructions: